# How to get rid of laravel_session cookie from Laravel application?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to get rid of laravel_session.

I've tried to create a middleware for it

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-51-disable-session-and-cookies-for-some-routes

Change the driver to use : `array` `file`, `database`

None of that works. Every time I refresh, I always see this:

[image]

How can I achieve this? Is it even possible to do ?

Comment: This is the cookie sent by browser, clear it when testing new setups (clear web browser cache/history)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I have specific routes that I don't want Laravel to use laravel_session. 
You can apply that to any routes you want.

Ex. For example, if you want to apply to only these 2 routes :

`url1` or `url2`

`Route::get('/url1', 'SampleController@fnName');`

`Route::get('/url2', 'SampleController@fnName2');`

---

Create **/app/Http/Middleware/StartSessionMiddleware.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Config;

use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession as BaseStartSession;

class StartSessionMiddleware extends BaseStartSession
{

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

        if($request->is('url1') || $request->is('url2')) {
            Config::set('session.driver', 'array');
        }

        return parent::handle($request, $next);
    }
}
```

Register that by appending a line into **/app/Http/Kernel.php**

`\App\Http\Middleware\StartSessionMiddleware::class,`

and now, that laravel_session should not be there anymore for those 2 routes.

I hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to start a session at all, in Laravel 5.1 go to app/Http/Kernel.php and comment out the session-related parts:

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    // \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    // \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
];
```

Note that it's not sufficient to only rip out the `StartSession` middleware, you'll also have to disable `ShareErrorsFromSession` and `VerifyCsrfToken` since they rely on a session being present. If you want more logic like excluding it for certain routes, you could override the StartSession middelware. I don't know of any other side effects though because I haven't tested it.

If you don't need sessions or all the website related functions because, for instance, you're only building an API, you might want to have a look at [Laravel Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/) that is streamlined for this purpose.

And by the way: The session driver only defines where/how to store the session *server-side*. From the client side it's still just an encrypted cookie.

Comment: As soon as I commented out those 3 lines, I got this error `Session store not set on request.` - do you have anything suggestions ?

Comment: @ihue Not quite sure why that is, I've just tried it out myself and it seems to work so far. Make sure you have everything cleaned up properly, maybe you could even try to restart your web server. You could also try to set the Session driver to `array` to make sure there is at least some functionality if something needs it and that it gets cleared after the request. Where exactly does that error occure? Make sure there is nothing in your views depending on the sessions (like checking for `$errors` or rendering the CSRF token).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone searching, in Laravel 5.5+ you can change the env variable `SESSION_COOKIE=`. If you have a little older app, you might need to set this in `config/session.php` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if($request->path('url1') || $request->path('url2')) {
```

to look for a url path. For EU Cookie tracking I used:

```
<?php
  namespace App\Http\Middleware;

  use Closure;
  use Config;

  use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession as BaseStartSession;

  class StartSessionMiddleware extends BaseStartSession
  {

/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

    if(!isset($_COOKIE['my-cookie'])) {
        Config::set('session.driver', 'array');
    }

    return parent::handle($request, $next);
  }
}
```

with my-cookie as the name of the cookie you are setting when user accepts.